# Select para Alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando estabelecer um select para ser uma `alias` de um registro.
Não sei ainda se há essa possibilidade, alguém poderia me esclarecer essa dúvida?

ex: `select 1 as (select dia_da_semana from ano where dia = 1 and mes = 10)`

Exemplo acima de mais ou menos como seria minha ideia.

Answer (score 0):

O que pretende pode ser solucionado recorrendo a SQL dinâmico:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT 1 AS ''' + (SELECT dia_da_semana FROM ano WHERE dia = 1 AND mes = 10) + ''''

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Desta forma precisa-se necessariamente fazer através de uma função ou procedure?

Answer (score 0):

No postgresql o alias 'e nesse formato:

```
select (select dia_da_semana from ano where dia = 1 and mes = 10) as 1
```

mas provavelmente iria te retorna um erro caso tenha mais de um valor, pq seria uma subquery, caso queira em formato de array voce pode fazer dessa forma:

```
select ARRAY(select dia_da_semana from ano where dia = 1 and mes = 10) as 1
```

exemplo:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vBmaYMc6AZPkvuGimCogad/1

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que sua tabela `ano` seja algo parecido com isso:

```
CREATE TABLE ano AS
SELECT
  to_char(s,'YYYY')::INTEGER AS ano,
  to_char(s,'MM')::INTEGER AS mes,
  to_char(s,'DD')::INTEGER AS dia,
  (ARRAY['DOMINGO','SEGUNDA','TERÇA','QUARTA','QUINTA','SEXTA','SABADO'])[EXTRACT(DOW FROM s)+1] AS dia_da_semana
 FROM
   generate_series('01/01/2022','31/12/2023', '1 day'::interval) AS s;
```

Dados:

```
|----------------------------------|
| dia_da_semana | dia | mes |  ano |
|---------------|-----|-----|------|
|        SABADO |   1 |   1 | 2022 |
|       DOMINGO |   2 |   1 | 2022 |
|       SEGUNDA |   3 |   1 | 2022 |
.
.
.
|        SABADO |  30 |  12 | 2023 |
|       DOMINGO |  31 |  12 | 2023 |
|----------------------------------|
```

Talvez os exemplos a seguir possam te ajudar a entender melhor o problema:

**Exemplo #1)** Retorna registros com `ALIAS` para o campo "existe" e para o registro `xpto`:

```
select 1 AS existe
from (select dia_da_semana from ano where dia = 1 and mes = 10) AS xpto;
```

Saída:

```
|--------|
| existe |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      1 |
|--------|
```

**Exemplo #2)** `ALIAS` para o `record`:

```
SELECT 
  xpto.dia_da_semana
 FROM
   (SELECT dia_da_semana FROM ano WHERE dia = 1 AND mes = 10) AS xpto;
```

Saída:

```
|---------------|
| dia_da_semana |
|---------------|
|        SABADO |
|       DOMINGO |
|---------------|
```

**Exemplo #3)** Verifica se ao menos um registro de dia/mes existe na tabela
`ano`:

```
select exists(select dia_da_semana from ano where dia = 1 and mes = 10);
```

Saída:

```
|--------|
| exists |
|--------|
|   true |
|--------|
```

**Exemplo #4)** `ALIAS` para a tabela `ano`:

```
select
  xpto.dia_da_semana,
  xpto.dia,
  xpto.mes,
  xpto.ano
from
   ano AS xpto
 where
   dia = 1 and
   mes = 10;
```

Saída:

```
|----------------------------------|
| dia_da_semana | dia | mes |  ano |
|---------------|-----|-----|------|
|        SABADO |   1 |  10 | 2022 |
|       DOMINGO |   1 |  10 | 2023 |
|----------------------------------|
```

[SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2a71b/6)